# What are feasible options of self-employment for mathematicians?

Tags: germany, self-employment

So I'm a mathematician in Germany wondering about alternatives to corporate life. To give some more background, I specialized in insurance mathematics, with some sound knowledge in finance and optimization. My coding abilities are okay but definitely not sufficient to become a software engineer, plus I don't see myself being a programmer.

I have started looking around and also tried to think of reasonable ways to make a living out of my skills but have not come up with a good answer yet. So any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Gambling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_Blackjack_Team) obviously!

Answer (score 4):

First, if you are only trying to get away from working for a major corperation, working for a startup or for the government can be very different from working for a big corperation in very different ways.

If you really want to be self-employed you can try to sell your skills as some kind of business consulting. But be aware that if you do something like that a major part of what you do is acquiring customers and doing the paperwork associated to being a business, neither of which has much to do with your math skills. Being successfully self-employed depends to a large extent on your ability to market yourself to potential customers, possibly more so then your ability to solve their problems.